# How to have multiple pages in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a simple electron app set up (I'm just learning electron) and I want to be able to have a button take me to another page. I'm making a rock paper scissors application right now, and I have a problem. I need to make it so that when I click `play`, it takes me to a page where I can select either `rock`, `paper`, or `scissors`. After I click one of the three choices it loads another page where a variable of the user's choice was passed from the last page to this one. On this page, it generates a random number as the computer's choice and determines whether the user has won. I haven't yet found a way to effectively do this. Unlike a webpage, electron apps don't have URLs, and I can't just reroute the user to somewhere else.

My question is, how can I make it switch pages and pass variables from one page to another?

Comment: Does localStorage do what you want? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage - Or just don't change page and render different HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Electron is for putting JavaScript apps as desktop apps. How Electron does that is by emulating a browser. That being said, you could get to different pages just like you would as if it was any other web application. Think of electron as taking the place of express.

Passing variables between pages is a bit more difficult. To achieve this you could use state management frameworks like react but you could also just use localStorage to set variables before you switch pages and then get the variable when you get to the next page.

From the Mozilla docs:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
localStorage.clear();
```

Refrence link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage